# click function called multiple times

Tags: jquery

The thing is there are various products on my homepage , on clicking on it there is a popup opening after it. There is a like button on the modal popup. On clicking on it i fire ajax and populate the database and close it , but when i open another popup model and click on the like button the ajax fires two times similarly after closing and opening another popup the ajax call increases.

I tried to make modal html to blank on clicking the close button on button. but, it is not working.
On the home page

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="prod_detail">
                <div class="modal fade" id="prod_viewd" role="dialog">

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

this is the container where i am populating the data .

This is the like icon html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="vf-item-fullview-icon change">
    <span class="ProductFullView_like lstCng">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/blog/feed_image/likeBlack.png" />
    </span> 
</a>
```

and this is the code for click

```
$(document.body).on('click','.change', function(e) {  
    alert('clicked');
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Like',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "product_id=" + $('#product_id').val() + "&from=product",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            if (response.exists == "1")
            {
                //$('#success_wish').html(response.message);
                //$('#success_wish').show("slow");
                // $('.hello').attr('src', swap).attr("data",current);
                $(".product_like_li").html(response.likeText);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_wish').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
            }
            if (response.exists == "2")
            {
                //$('#success_error').html(response.message);
                //$('#success_error').show("slow");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_error').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = base_url + 'Login'
                }, 3000);
            }
            if (response.exists == "0")
            {
                $('#success_error').html(response.message);
                $('#success_error').show("slow");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_error').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from the way you name the element. Maybe you have multiple elements which have the same class name. That's how: *I do this, but why that?*

Comment: @TânNguyễn i have already checked that , i think when i click to open the modal the number of instances of modal = number of ajax called

Comment: you sample code is not enough to understand, maybe it's something related to how you add the event listener...

Comment: can you show your html or better to make a fiddle for it

Comment: So, what's happen if we open modal via using `id` instead of `class`? And then try to change the way to make ajax request to `$('.modal').on('click', 'button', function () { /*code goes here*/ })`

Comment: @TânNguyễn edited

Comment: @NegiRox edited

Comment: i would suggest to bind a click function on page load

Comment: the problem here is how you add the event listener, it will fire for ANY ".change", so it will fire one time at first, then 2 times, then 3 times ecc ecc.
You can remove the previous .change element after the ajax call response or (more effectively) run your code inside a "$(document).ready" function and bind your click event only to  ".change" elements container

Comment: (and remove the previous ".change" element anyway is a best practice unless you expect to reuse it)

Answer (score 1):

Try to unbind the click event whenever page loads.You can use unbind method as follows.

```
$(document).unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. It seems that `$(document.body).on` event is getting bind each time you open popup.

```
$(document.body).off('click','.change');
$(document.body).on('click','.change', function(e) {  
    // Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use off to unbind the events:

```
$('.commonClose').off('click').click(function(e) {  
    $('.prod_vbody').html('');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please add your function on document.ready function something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.change').on('click', function(e) {  
    alert('clicked');
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Like',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "product_id=" + $('#product_id').val() + "&from=product",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            if (response.exists == "1")
            {
                //$('#success_wish').html(response.message);
                //$('#success_wish').show("slow");
                // $('.hello').attr('src', swap).attr("data",current);
                $(".product_like_li").html(response.likeText);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_wish').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
            }
            if (response.exists == "2")
            {
                //$('#success_error').html(response.message);
                //$('#success_error').show("slow");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_error').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = base_url + 'Login'
                }, 3000);
            }
            if (response.exists == "0")
            {
                $('#success_error').html(response.message);
                $('#success_error').show("slow");
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_error').hide("slow")
                }, 3000);
            }
        }
    });

   });
})
```